# Run Gui while my scripts are still running on AHK

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

I have a LUA interface in AHK which executes the following loop:

```lua
function ApplicationInit()
    -- Load application
    loadGameClient()
    --soundPlay("sounds/xxx.wav")

    -- Load player of current client
    if Player:loadPlayer() then
        gameActivate()
    end

    -- Send Status Message On Window
    while true do
        if not IsPause then
            Module.libOnTimer()
        end
        Status:Update()
        sleep(10)
    end
end
```

But I would like to show a GUI without stopping this loop.

Comment: Could you post your code inside a code block instead of as an image?

Comment: https://ghostbin.co/paste/ftxrb

Comment: Here part of ahk https://ghostbin.co/paste/xkovp

Comment: Nobody can help me?  If my program is running a loop, what can I do to display a GUI or "window", I am creating a kind of bot that reads the client's memory to do things